# Multibyte replace not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does one work and the other doesn't?

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'IAșI' ,N'ș','x') -- doesn't match (returns 'IAșI')
SELECT REPLACE('IAșI' ,'ș','x') -- works (returns 'IAxI')
```

My guess would be that in the second example SQL Server sees 'ș' as 2 characters (0x19 02) and doesn't do some collation optimisations that ruin the multibyte match.

What should be done for the multibyte example to work?

Comment: @mark_s what is the difference between SQL Server and MSSQL?
I usually use MSSQL notation when searching as SQL Server is too generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't explain why the first one isn't working (perhaps some subtlety of that particular Unicode character). This produces a rather unexpected result:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'IAșI', N'șI', 'x') -- returns 'xAșx'
```

The second one will appear to work because SQL Server replaces multi-byte characters with '?' when casting down to varchar.

This small example demonstrates the behavior, as all arguments will be converted to varchar literals:

```
SELECT 'IAșI', REPLACE('IA?I', 'ș', 'x'), REPLACE('IAșI', '?', 'x') -- returns 'IAxI'
```

**EDIT**: Seems to be collation related.

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'IAșI' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, N'ș', 'x') -- doesn't match (returns 'IAșI')
SELECT REPLACE(N'IAșI' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, N'ș', 'x') -- returns 'IAxI'
```

Comment: Seems to be something fixed in the more recent collations. `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` returns `'IAxI'`